Dynamic change of custom dropdown
I have a custom  dropdown in my angular project. in one of my component using this custom dropdown data should be dynamic. means in
loop this dropdown is calling if data shown in drop down is
[Apple,orange,grapes,pineapple]
row 2 dropdown  [orange,grapes,pineapple] 
row 3 dropdown  [orange,grapes,pineapple] 

In my multiselect my fuctionality is creating model array which contains name to be show inside dropdown, status, id(means) index, and other functionality is to emit selectedData
but each of this functionality is given in ngonchange so in what ever method i filtered data in parent component and input to mutiselect, it trigger ngonchange, call first functioninitModelcheck inside emitdata function
change selectedData call will go to dropdown change event looping this makes page slow, I won't found a solution
This is my mutiselect code
     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {    
    this.model    = [];
    this.selected = [];
    this.isDisabled = this.isDisabled;
    this.emitData      = this.emitData;
    this.showAdd = false;
    this.addNewLoad = false;
    this.textEntered = '';
 
 
    this.initCheckModelStatus();
  

  }
  
  initCheckModelStatus(): void {
    if (this.buttonName) {
      this.value = this.buttonName;
    } else {
      this.value = this.itemName;
    }
    if (this.data) {

 
    if (!this.multiselector && !this.toggleMultiSelect) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.data[i][this.itemName] == 'Select') {
          this.statTemp = true;
          break;
        } else {
          this.statTemp = false;
      }
      }
      if (!this.statTemp) {
        this.data.splice(0, 0, { [this.itemName]: 'Select' });
        //console.log(this.data);
        
        if (this.selectedItems) {
          this.selectedItems = Object.assign([Number(this.selectedItems[0]) + 1]);
      }
    }
    }
  
       this.isDisabled = false;

      for (let index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++) {
        let status = true;
        if (this.status) {
             
          if (this.data[index][this.status] && this.data[index][this.value]) {
            this.selected.push(this.data[index]);
          }
          this.itemNameCheck(index, this.data[index][this.status]);
        } else if (this.selectedItems) {
          if (this.multiselector) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.selectedItems.length; j++) {
              if (index == this.selectedItems[j]) {
                this.itemNameCheck(index, true);
                this.selected.push(this.data[index]);
                status = false;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (status) {
              this.itemNameCheck(index, false);
          }
          } else {

             for (let j = 0; j < this.selectedItems.length; j++) {
                if (index == this.selectedItems[j]) {
                   this.itemNameCheck(index, true);
                   this.selected.push(this.data[index]);
                   status = false;
                   break;
                }
             }
            if (status) {
              this.itemNameCheck(index, false);
          }
        }
        } else {
          this.itemNameCheck(index, false);
        }
      }
    } else {
 
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
    if (this.model.length == this.selected.length) {
      this.checkBoxValue = true;
    } else {
      this.checkBoxValue = false;
    }
    if(this.isexcludeListChange){
      this.emitSelectedData();

    }
   
  }


  itemNameCheck(index, status) {
    
    if (this.data[index][this.itemName]) {
      if(this.excludedList.length){

this.excludedList.forEach(item=>item[this.itemName] !== this.data[index][this.itemName])
      
      
      if(this.showLogo){
        this.model.push({
          'name'  : this.data[index][this.itemName],
          'id'    : index,
          'status': status,
          'flag_image_path':this.data[index]?.flag_image_path
        });
      }
      else{
 
      this.model.push({
        'name'  : this.data[index][this.itemName],
        'id'    : index,
        'status': status,
        'flag_image_path':null

      });
    
    }
  }
    } else if (this.data[index]) {
   

      if(this.showLogo){

       this.model.push({
        'name'  : this.data[index],
        'id'    : index,
        'status': status,
        'flag_image_path':this.data[index].flag_image_path

      });
    }
    else{
  

      this.model.push({
        'name'  : this.data[index],
        'id'    : index,
        'status': status,
        'flag_image_path':null

      });
    }
    }
   
 
  }

  inputClick(selected): void {
    this.selected = [];
    if (this.multiselector) { // for  multiSelector
      for (let index = 0; index < this.data.length ; index++) {
        if (this.model[index].name === selected.name && this.model[index].id == selected.id) {
            this.model[index].status = !this.model[index].status;
            break;
        }
      }
      this.model.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item.status) {
            this.selected.push(this.data[index]);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.openWindowStatus = false;
      for (let index = 0; index < this.data.length ; index++) {
        if (this.model[index].name === selected.name && this.model[index].id == selected.id) {
              this.model[index].status = true;
              this.selected.push(this.data[index]);
        } else {
            this.model[index].status = false;
        }
      }
    }
    this.checkBoxValue = this.model.every(function(value) {
      return value.status == true;
    });
  
    this.emitSelectedData();
    this.textEntered = '';
    if(this.showLogo){
    }
 
  }

 
  emitSelectedData(): void {
    if (this.selected.length) {
      if (this.selected[0][this.value]) {
        this.viewFirstSelectedData = this.selected[0][this.value];
      } else {
        this.viewFirstSelectedData = this.selected[0];
      }
    } else {
      this.viewFirstSelectedData = ' ';
    }
    let selected      = this.selected;
    let selectedIndex = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.model.length; index++) {
      if (this.model[index].status) {
        selectedIndex.push(index);
      }
    }

    if (!this.multiselector) {
      if (this.selected.length) {
        if (this.selected[0][this.itemName] == 'Select') {
          selected = [];
          selectedIndex = [];
        } else {
          if (this.id.includes('filter')) {
          } else {
            selectedIndex = [selectedIndex[0] - 1];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    (this.emitData) ? this.selectedData.emit({selected, selectedIndex}) : null;
  }

